# Changing Apple rescue email

Tags: ipad

How do I change my Apple Rescue email.  It is no longer valid and there is no edit function to change it? The only edit function in this area is to change my challenge questions, which I have done.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried doing this via the [Manage Apple ID](https://appleid.apple.com/) page?

If you use two-step verification or two-factor authentication, you have a notification email address, not a rescue email address.

For more info about additional emails and rescue emails with your Apple ID read [this](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201356). This page also provides step-by-step instructions on how to add/edit these emails.